# Navigate a rootless dom with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Given this html string:

```
var string = "<div></div><p></p>";
```

I create a jQuery object with it:

```
var dom = $(string);
```

Is there any chance to use selectors to point to one of its tag? Without embed it all in a newly created one, of course.

```
dom.find("p");// []
```

Comment: Of course. When you have a list of items, you usually want to *filter* them down to the item or items you want.

Comment: [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/): "_Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element._" vs. [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/): "_Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there's no root element you'll need to use `filter()` to get top level elements:

```js
var string = "<div></div><p></p>";
var $dom = $(string).appendTo('body'); // appendTo() is only for purposes of this demo
$dom.filter("p").text('hello world!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find` looks inside of the element. In your case though you're creating a `div` and a paragraph next to one another. Move the paragraph inside the `div` and your code will work.

Or you can wrap both of those elements into a third, parent.

```
var string = "<div><p></p></div>";

var dom = $(string);

console.log(dom.find("p"));
```

Comment: I guess the html has a purpose the way it is, but your solution will work when traversing down the dom

Comment: But he's using .find so he might as well know what it does. Rory has covered .filter in case that's what op wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "<div></div><p></p>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = $(parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html"));

//work with dom
dom.find("p");
```

the parser will create an html document (not appended to your document).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method to work with an HTML snippet that may contain anything is to use a temporary parent node, then use/extract its children.

```
var $root = $('<div></div>').append(yourHtml);
$root.find('p').addClass('foo');// or whatever
$('.bar').append($root.contents());// put filtered content in your DOM; or
var filteredHtml = $root.html();// get it back to a string of markup
```

Now the code is less coupled to the contents and more flexible because you don't have to know ahead of time whether you'd need to use `filter()`, `find()` or both.